# how to add padding when calling L.map.getBounds()

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

My mapbox/leaflet map has a 100px padding on top (that is partially covered by an overlay).

Markers that are visible in that overlay area should not be included when using `getBounds()` to check markers with `bounds.contains(marker.coords)`

I can only find a way to pad LngLatBounds by percentage, is there a way similar to `fitBounds` options where you can specify a `paddingTopLeft`.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? If so, could you please accept the answer, or post one of your own (and accept that)? Doing so would help others who read this in future

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting the map bounds, run [`map.containerPointToLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) twice, specifying the points (relative to the map's container), something like `[0, 100]` for your top-left corner and the container's size for the bottom-right.

Then, just create a new `L.LatLngBounds` with the results of those two calls.

Comment: [Leaflet-active-area](https://github.com/Mappy/Leaflet-active-area) and [Leaflet.ControlledBounds](https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.ControlledBounds) plugins could be great for this use case. I wonder if they are still compatible with Leaflet 1.0?